# How does Torbjörn's turret choose its target?

Tags: overwatch

I feel like there is of course an obvious proximity factor, but when I (as Pharrah in my example) try to sneak a peak from behind a corner and shoot the turret one rocket at a time, it seems to often target me even if there are other potential targets nearby.

So I was wondering if there is any other logic here other than "The turret targets the first enemy it sees and shoots it until it is dead, or leaves its line of sight" ?

**Edit**: After some games, I have a strong feeling that the turret has a preference for characters it can kill quickly (like Pharrah or Genji) and is less prone to shoot tanks. *This is a subjective view but in the same game I played genji and zarya and found myself targeted by the turret a lot more often with genji.*

**Edit 2**: I tried to be careful of its behavior during my last games and the turret definitely takes into account who is attacking it. I was farther away from the turret than my teammates and I started firing at it. After a few rockets (I just needed one more to destroy it), the turret changed its target to me although there were still other targets much closer.

Comment: It could target the biggest threat to its well being, or the enemy that's the most out of the way, but I don't have any solid evidence.

Comment: Yeah I feel there might a "threat factor" just like you said, because the turret seems to counter attack quite often when I shoot it.

Comment: I'm thinking it just picks closest target and keeps shooting until it is dead or leaves LOS. Because i've had times when a Reinhardt is tanking the turret while the Pharrah is closer and shooting it.  Maybe it counter attacks because the person it was attacking either died or moved out of LOS?

Comment: Sounds like a job for !!SCIENCE!!. I might be able to test this if I can get enough of my friends to help

Comment: I'd love to think it chose its target based solely on proximity, but there have been too many games on Hanamura where I am strafing through the antechamber part with ~1 hp and it flicks to me and insta-kills me. I think there might be a weight or a preference for targets it can easily kill, as well.

Comment: That's what motivated me to ask this question. The turret's targeting always seems so, let's say, appropriate that I have a hard time believing it's only bad luck ^^.
@KizTrap I knew you would be enthousiatic about researching this, you're the official overwatch scientist ! :-)

Comment: I definitely don't think it's proximity. I was on Route 66 yesterday as Zen, flanked behind the turret (practically on top of it) and started hitting it with my orbs. Damn thing never turned to face me, just kept shooting my teammates across the way.

Comment: I can't help to wonder if Pharrah is not a primary target for the turret, but maybe i'm biased because I play her a lot. But this could be logical as Torb seems to be an obvious counter to Pharrah.

Comment: @kerwan :o I am? Thanks! Didn't get a chance to test last night, might not tonight- upgrading pc firmware so Windows 10 will be angry with me most likely. If I get a chance I will though

Comment: If you need people to test, feel free to add me on battle.net. There's a link on my profile. Whenever I'm online I'll be happy to help SCIENCE ^^ !

Comment: I have not done any testing, but I believe the turret targets whatever target enters its line of sight first. It will then continue firing until its target is either dead or leaves LoS, at which point it will target the next closest hero within line of sight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tested this myself and according to what I have looked at the turret focuses on the target that enters its '*line of sight*' first.

**The testing that I did:**

I convinced a member of the enemy team to place down a turret as I walked out, letting the turret fire into me(I was playing Roadhog). While this was happening we had a Genji dart in front of me and run towards the turret to check if the turret would switch to the player that was closest. However, the turret only started shooting at the Genji once I(Roadhog), died.  Therefore, Genji was the only one left in it's '*line of sight*' and he became the target.

> "After some games, I have a strong feeling that the turret has a preference for characters it can kill quickly (like Pharrah or Genji) and is less prone to shoot tanks."

You probably noticed that it focused on characters like Pharrah or Genji because they are both very mobile characters that in most cases enter the '*line of sight*' first.

> "I tried to be careful of its behavior during my last games and the turret definitely takes into account who is attacking it. I was farther away from the turret than my teammates and I started firing at it."

The turret may have targeted you here because all your teammates where behind cover and you were the last character in the turrets '*line of sight*'. So essentially you have really crappy luck.

**TL;DR:**

- Turret focuses on character that first enters the '*line of sight*'
- Characters with mobility most likely enter '*line of sight*' first
- @kerwan is unlucky

Comment: Have you tested where 2 targets come into line of sight at as close to the same time as you can manage, then having the one NOT being shot start attacking the turret to see if it switches?

Comment: This does show that the turret locks onto the first eligible target until it becomes ineligible (dies or leaves LOS). What still needs to be determined is how the target is selected if there are multiple eligible targets at the moment it switches (e.g. 3 characters, 1 is locked on and dies, which of the other two is selected?).